# VBA - multiple file open, copy and paste special (only values) to new file

Tags: excel, vba

This is a bit customization I am looking for. I have very small query; I am copying same range of cells from the excel file in a folder to a summary.xlsm, but want to paste the values only (Currently the code is pasting the formula from the source workbook).

I can understand it is some tweaking required here:

```
 c = 0
        Set rS = wS.Range(csSRng)
        'copy source range to current target row
        For Each Cel In rS
            Cel.Copy rT.Offset(, c) 'next column
            c = c + 1
        Next Cel
```

Full code is as following:

```
Sub copyMultFiles()
    Dim rS As Range, rT As Range, Cel As Range
    Dim wBs As Workbook 'source workbook
    Dim wS As Worksheet 'source sheet
    Dim wT As Worksheet 'target sheet
    Dim x As Long 'counter
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arrFiles() As String 'list of source files
    Dim myFile As String 'source file

    '    change these to suit requirements
    Const csMyPath As String = "C:\Users\Amit.Awasthi\Desktop\Jan_DRB\Cases\" 'source folder
    Const csMyFile As String = "*.xls" 'source search pattern
    Const csSRng As String = "$D$3,$C$20,$C$27,$C$35,$C$136,$C$163" 'source range
    Const csTRng As String = "$B$2" 'target range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '   target sheet
    Set wT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'change to suit
    '   clear sheet
    ' wT.Cells.Clear 'may not want this, comment out!!!

'   aquire list of files
    ReDim arrFiles(1 To 1)
    myFile = Dir$(csMyPath & csMyFile, vbNormal)
    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        arrFiles(UBound(arrFiles)) = myFile
        ReDim Preserve arrFiles(1 To UBound(arrFiles) + 1)
        myFile = Dir$
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve arrFiles(1 To UBound(arrFiles) - 1)

    Set rT = wT.Range(csTRng)

    ' loop thru list of files
    For x = 1 To UBound(arrFiles)
        Set wBs = Workbooks.Open(csMyPath & arrFiles(x), False, True) 'open wbook
        Set wS = wBs.Worksheets("BC_EWB_RV_MOD") 'change sheet to suit

        c = 0
        Set rS = wS.Range(csSRng)
        'copy source range to current target row
        For Each Cel In rS
            Cel.Copy rT.Offset(, c) 'next column
            c = c + 1
        Next Cel

        wBs.Close False
        Set rT = rT.Offset(1) 'next row
        DoEvents
    Next x 'next book

    Erase arrFiles

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Set rS = wS.Range(csSRng)
    'copy source range to current target row
    For Each Cel In rS
        Cel.Copy
        rT.Offset(, c).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
        c = c + 1
    Next Cel
```

or just:

```
    Set rS = wS.Range(csSRng)
    'copy source range to current target row
    For Each Cel In rS
        rT.Offset(, c).Value = Cel.Value
        c = c + 1
    Next Cel
```